# How to format text as bold sent to google chat room using webhook with google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have set up a webhook to a Google Chat room to send messages using data from a google sheet, using google script. Everything is working fine except I want to make some of the text appear in bold format in the google chat room, but am unable to do so. Below is my code. Can someone advise me on how to go about doing this?

```
if (localMoneyReceived == 0){

data = "No money has been Received." + String.fromCharCode(10) + "End of report";

}


var data = {
  text: data
};


var payload = JSON.stringify(data);

var options = {
  method: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
  payload: payload,
  muteHttpExceptions: true
};

var webhook = URL;
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(webhook, options);
```

So the text "No money has been received", I would like it to appear bold in the google chat room.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe Google Chat accepts * as a character for bold. So wrap the string with * your string * to make it bold.  Checkout the Google Chat API: https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/basic#using_formatted_text_in_messages

Comment: Thanks I got it to work using the * wrapped around the string

Comment: Can you accept the answer below, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Google Chat API, Wrap your message in `*` character to make it bold.

See Google Chat API Message Formatting [here](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/basic#using_formatted_text_in_messages)